# Import issue is react native

Tags: react-native

React Native: Import declaration must be at the top level of module.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLzWh.png)

I am facing this error while running the app after build completion in android studio. None of the answer is helping me yet, please suggest me any way to fix this issue as i am unable to run the app from last 4 days.
I have attached image for your understanding

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjGB3.png

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

check the file properly you have imported somewhere in middle of your code or in bottom check line by line or just find import in file where are they

Comment: the error comes even after removing all the import statements in my project.